# SVG flashes during CSS transition

Tags: html, css, svg

I've been developing a new company website, and to ensure it looks good on retina, I have been using SVG icons, something I've never really done before. However, I'm having a bit of an issue when trying to apply a CSS transition to the background-image, which is an SVG.

When the transition begins, the icon disappears, and once it finishes, the new icon appears in its place. If I use PNGs however, it works as it should. Is this a browser limitation? Or I am not doing something I should be? No matter what background settings I've tried, I can't get it to fade smoothly.

Watch the phone icon (SVG) compared to the logo (PNG).

[image]

**CSS of element:**

```
nav#header-nav div#phone-number {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-image: url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0554/1957/t/4/assets/phone-white.svg?19873);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  background-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 28px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

nav#header-nav.small div#phone-number {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-image: url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0554/1957/t/4/assets/phone.svg?19873);
}
```

**HTML of element:**

```
<div id="phone-number">(555) 867-5309</div>
```

Comment: You can't transition a background image with CSS (yet) as it has no intermediate values. It's either one thing or another...no halfway etc.

Comment: could you please provide your html.

Comment: Added HTML of the element. 

Paulie_D, I've done it with my logo just fine as  PNG.

Comment: And that's where the icon is set right?

Comment: Yep, the icon is just the background image. It works fine as a PNG, just not an SVG.

Comment: Somebody voted to close the question... I wish they'd provide their reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, by using `SVG` you can not fade between two icons. However you can still set just one of them and use the `Fill` property.

Try separate the icon from the text or include the icon inside the `div` and then animate the `Fill` property instead.

Example:

```
#icon{
   transition: fill 0.5s ease in-out;
   fill:black;
}
#phone-number:hover #icon{
   fill:white;
}
```

Comment: So just link it as an image with an IMG tag?

Comment: Use `<svg>` tag or an `<object>` tag.

Comment: @Devin I have never tried an `<image>` tag with an `svg` image before tho, but i think it works yea.

Comment: I'm using a CDN (Shopify) so looks like cross domain styling doesn't work. I'd rather not have all the extra SVG code inline with the rest of the HTML, but it looks like I may have to.

Comment: Well yes it is the only way to do so, unless it is not necessarily to use an `SVG` and convert it to `PNG` format instead and using your own code.

Comment: Yeah, may just fall back to PNG for this project, but this is good info for the future.